# Integration of exponential raised with Brownian Motion wrt the Brownian Motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, itos-lemma

I have to derive several things for my thesis, however, I have the following expression:

$$
\int^{t}_{0} \exp\{\sigma W_{t}\}.dW_{t}
$$

Does anyone know what the solution for this is?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike for many ordinary integrals in calculus there is not always a solution in Ito calculus.

***Partial Answer and Hints***

The process
$$
M_t=\exp\{\sigma\,W_t-\sigma^2t/2\}
$$
is a martingale that satisfies
$$
dM_t=\sigma\,M_t\,dW_t\,,\quad\text{ or in integral form }M_t=1+\int_0^t\sigma\,M_s\,dW_s\,.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\int_0^t\sigma\,M_s\,dW_s=\sigma\int_0^t\exp\{\sigma\,W_s-\sigma^2s/2\}\,dW_s=M_t-1=\exp\{\sigma\,W_t-\sigma^2t/2\}-1\,.
$$
If you want to get rid of the $-\sigma^2s/2$ term in the exponential you could apply Girsanov's theorem which will introduce a drift in the integrating BM $dW_t$.

I think some integral will always remain "unsolved".